# asp:Button not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, button, gridview

this is my scenario:

I want to display a button(btnGenerate) based on the amount of rows displayed in my gridview. I've gotten it to display for a second then it goes away again. I'm using the onclientclick of one of my other buttons(btnImport). What I think is causing the problem is that on the same button(btnImport)'s OnClick event two gridview's performs for each a databind. Could this be the problem? I have written a script using javascript to perform this task from the client side. Is there a better way to do it? What can I do to fix my problem?

Here is my code that I have so far:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnImport" Text="Load Data from File" 
     BackColor="#990000" ForeColor="White" nowrap OnClick="btnImport_Click" 
     style="display:none" OnClientClick="DisplayButtonGenerate()"/>

<asp:Button ID="btnGenerate" runat="server" Text="Generate New Stock Codes" 
    BackColor="#990000" ForeColor="White" OnClick="btnGenerate_Click" 
    style="display:none" />
```

I have two gridviews : ErrorsGrid that displays all the faulty records and InventoryGrid that displays the records that are correct. Like I said above, the idea is to display btnGenerate if ErrorsGrid has rowCount=0.

```
protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InventoryGrid.DataBind();
    ErrorsGrid.DataBind();        
}

protected void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FinalMessage.AppendLine(_InsertWrapper.PostData());
}
```

Here is the script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function DisplayButtonGenerate() {
        var rowCount = <%=ErrorsGrid.Rows.Count %>;
        var buttonGen = document.getElementById("<%=btnGenerate.ClientID%>");
        if(rowCount == 0)
        {
            buttonGen.style.display = "block";
        }
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: After showing `btnGenerate` button what you want to do? You want to skip the post back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your btnImport has server-side `OnClient` and client-side `OnClientClick` both set. I guess what's happening is the client-side is called first, shows the button, then the server-side one kicks in, the page gets refreshed from the server, and your button is hidden again. You can do it in one way or another, but not both:

Server-side: Remove the `OnClientClick` & `style="display:none"` & JavaScript, set the `Visible` property of the button to false, and in the code-behind click event on the server add:

```
if(ErrorsGrid.Rows.Count == 0)
    btnImport.Visible = True;
```

Client-side: Return false from the JavaScript function to the `OnClientClick`:

```
OnClientClick="return DisplayButtonGenerate()"

function DisplayButtonGenerate() {
  ....
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Help! It added some knowledge to my understanding of asp and I choose to use the first choice. It was very simple and works great

Comment: You're very welcome. We're all learning in this world. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update `InventoryGrid,ErrorsGrid` grid controls in code after you click a button, you need to keep those in a `UpdatePanel`

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<contenttemplate>
 InventoryGrid,ErrorsGrid mark up
</contentTemplate>
<Triggers>
 //set async trigger as btnImport 
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Okay I've done that and it displays the button correctly but then my gridviews doesn't display their data

Comment: @user3180965, if you dont return false, it will execute `btnImport_Click` event, which is a postback. While you do a full postback you cant see the visibled button

Comment: @user3180965, Ok. I think you want to update the gridview data as well?

Comment: Better keep `InventoryGrid,ErrorsGrid, btnGenerate` in a update panel

Comment: Yes it needs to databind for both gridviews

Comment: @user3180965, updated my sample code. It looks like pseduo code

Comment: Thanks for the help! I didn't know how to use an update panel but you explained it quiet simple.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's breakdown your problem into steps.

- you click on btnImport, it first calls the `OnClientClick`, does client side processing
  and then does a full postback, goes to server side and processes its server side handler `OnClick`.
- after the `OnClick` handler is processed, the page again renders, the unconditioned code in the btnGenerate `display:none` again runs, and the default state is again rendered.

you see the problem? even if you are manipulating certain logic in your clientClick, it all resets on page reload, because your `btnImport` is doing that.

**Solutions:**

there are couple of things I can suggest.

1. Use UpdatePanel to prevent Postback of the entire page or
2. make your btnImport a client side button altogether, and do a post using xhr or jQuery's ajax.
3. Set the visibility of btnGenerate on the server side itself

most simple would be the 3rd one i.e. remove the onclientclick event from the code and change your btnImport to do this:

```
protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InventoryGrid.DataBind();
    ErrorsGrid.DataBind();        
    //set visibility of btnGenerate in Page_Load also;
    btnGenerate.Visible = ErrorsGrid.Rows.Count == 0;
}
```

and remove display:none from btnGenerate from client

Comment: The ErrorsGrid.Rows.Any(); gives an compiler error saying that GridViewCollection does not contain a definition for Any if I remove the script and did what you mentioned above

Comment: You will need `using System.Linq` abv in  your page, bt anyways, I've modified my code, checkitout now

Comment: Okay I changed that part and the logic was a bit wrong but I corrected it and it works now

if (ErrorsGrid.Rows.Count == 0)
        btnGenerate.Visible = true;

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a JS function here.

Simply check the datasource for ErrorsGrid `if count != 0` and if it's not just set the visibility of your button in codebehind.

Comment: That would be the ideal but I tried that and the statement
btnGenerate.Enable = true/false; does not execute correctly. It requires a postback to see the changes

Comment: And are you unable to do a postback?

Comment: yes and the main reason why I can't do that is that all the data processing and so on is done in an InventoryUpload wrapper so the list I need to access is inaccessable from the btnImport_Click method

Comment: `DisplayButtonGenerate()` will only display the button if there are no rows `if(rowCount == 0)`. Shouldn't that be `if(rowCount > 0) { ... }`

Comment: No, ErrorsGrid contains faulty records so if the gridview doesn't have any rows there are in effect no faulty records and the user can continue to submit the data...

Answer (score 0):

If i've understood your req. correctly, setting 'Visbible' property of button to true or false should work. i.e btnGenerate.Visible=true/false. Initially you can set the button visibility as false then based on the record count you can modify it in the required event handler.